# Best way to call sproc for all the results of query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

[SQL Server 2008 Std]

I have a stored procedure that is used to insert new data into a table, which works as expected. However I now need to call this stored procedure multiple times using the results of a query as the parameters.

e.g.

```
select 
   name, age, foo, bar 
from 
   sometable 
where 
   wobble = 'true'

exec insertProc name age foo bar
```

I know I can use a cursor to acheive this, but I keep reading that "cursors are bad"...but I don't know any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you not use `select into` as an alternative?

Comment: no, the sproc is doing more than just an insert (above is just an example, not the real thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use cursor. Other is to prepare your result set into temp table before calling the procedure and then supply it to the procedure ( you have to alter the procedure by adding table-value param as input param). Some info in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Comment: Wouldn't I need to still loop through my TVP rows?

Comment: In the procedure - No. You have to modify in such way that it can consume the result from that TVP.[Passing TVP to procedure](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/168)

Comment: I think I can do it this way...not sure, but might be worth a try.